# C# read in file using hex prints FFFFFF

Tags: c#, hex

very confused by this, when I read in a file using the code below when it gets to the end it prints out FFFFFF, could anyone explain this to me the text file only has numbers and letters in it? Any help would be most greatful!

```
        String fileDirectory = "C:\\t.txt";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileDirectory);

        int hexIn;

        for (int i = 0; (hexIn = reader.Read()) != -1; i++)
        {

            String s;
            s = hexIn.ToString("X2");
            int x = 0;
            while (x < 1)
            {
                hexIn = reader.Read();
                s = hexIn.ToString("X2");
                x++;
            }
            hexIn = reader.Read();
            s = hexIn.ToString("X2");
            MessageBox.Show(s);

        }
```

Comment: Are you *sure* it has only letters and numbers in it?  It probably also has line returns, spaces, and EOF markers.

Comment: What encoding is the file in? Are you sure your `StreamReader` uses the same encoding?

Comment: You mention that it prints out FFFFFF. Did you mean that literally? Is there a 2:1 ratio of F's to characters in the file as you would expect? Does each `MessageBox.Show(s);` call show a messagebox with FF in it?

Comment: I love this code.  The `while` loop is classic.

Answer (score 3):

You've got three `Read` calls per loop iteration, which means that any one of them could return -1 to indicate the end of the file. I suspect that's then being converted to FFFFFFFF, hence your output. Why do you have more than one `Read` call? And why aren't you reading a block at a time?

Comment: Sometimes the more glaring errors are right in front of our faces and we don't even notice them. I completely glossed over that.

Comment: I need more than one as its the only way I know how to skip through several bytes at a time. Not reading a block as I need to check each byte for a pattern.

Comment: @Jay: Well you can still check each byte as you go - but currently you're only checking for the end of the file one byte in three...

Answer (score 0):

The FFFFFF may also indicate an empty value. If you Hex editted Nintendo DS Roms you would see a whole bunch of FFFFFFFF at the end which is put there because the game is too small for the cartridge so in actual fact that file may have empty values at the end.